# Problem configuring dnsmasq for local subdomains

Tags: virtual-machines, internal-dns, dnsmasq, wildcard-subdomain

I've set up dnsmasq on a virtal machine server in order to handle static wildcard subdomains on my local home network for development purposes.

The idea is to have ***.local.myapp.com** resolve to the VM itself (bridged networking), running the http and dns server.

I've installed dnsmasq on the VM. And edited dnsmasq.conf to resolve to the VM's network IP:

```
# Add domains which you want to force to an IP address here.
# The example below send any host in doubleclick.net to a local
# webserver.
address=/local.myapp.com/192.168.1.5
```

After adding the VM's ip to resolv.conf, pinging foo.local.myapp.com properly resolved to the machine's IP. When I try to ping it from the host machine, however, it acts like the there's no local dns and happily skips to the resolving it via internet, returning the webhost IP address. I tried listing it as the name server on both the host OS and the network router. No dice.

I'm very new to this, so I know I am probably doing something remarkably dumb. Could anyone offer a guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem -- port 53 was closed on my prepackaged LAMP stack.

```
ufw allow 53
```

Problem solved. Apologies.